# Screen width for desktops and laptops applied to navbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do many of these websites like facebook, twitter and even stack exchange get their navbar to automatically be the size of the desktop/laptop screen width, I know they are not using width: 100%, hence a navbar resizing would take place. What technology are they using? is it media queries? or some javascript function that gets the screen width then apply that as the navbar width.

Comment: It's simple, they using CSS 3 or maybe some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it behaves exactly like stackoverflow nav-bar.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#fwcenter {
  width: 800px;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
#left {
  width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <center>
    <div id="fwcenter">
      <div id="left">
        left
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        right
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Hahah! got the concept! it is very cheeky and smart. The 100% always adjust to the screen width however there is an inner navbar with the same height but a specified width, which stops the navbar from resizing to give you the feel it fits every laptop and desktop screen width. could have never thought of that. Thanks!